# What's the best way to remove some divs (with selectors) from an html string using php?

Tags: php

I have the following text on a php variable:

```
<div class="keep">Content</div>
<div class="remove">Content</div>
<div class="keep">Content</div>
<div id="remove">Content</div>
```

I need to remove the div with id = remove and the one with class = remove, using php. The html could be more complex, basically I need to target a div with jquery-type selectors and the remove it and its content. Thanks.

Comment: Can you not simply not write them out in the first place? I'm not sure why you need to 'remove' them with php. Some more context would be very helpful

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843098/dom-manipulation-with-php has some decent links to DOM manipulation packages for PHP. Also if you Google php dom manipulation, you can find other resources like http://querypath.org/.

Comment: Yes @Andy, I get this html code from scraping a web page, so I need to get rid of them.

Comment: Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843098/dom-manipulation-with-php) has some decent links to DOM manipulation packages for PHP. Also if you Google "php dom manipulation", you can find other resources like [querypath.org](http://querypath.org). Some of these packages use selectors that you may be more familiar with.